# If $x^{37}=1,x\neq 1$, evaluate $\sum_{n=1}^{36}\frac{n}{(1+x^n+x^{2n}+x^{3n})^3}$

Tags: complex-numbers, summation, roots-of-unity

If $x$ satisfies $x^{37}=1,x\ne 1$, I want to evaluate

$$\sum_{n=1}^{36}\frac{n}{(1+x^n+x^{2n}+x^{3n})^3} = 
\sum_{n=1}^{36}n\left(\frac{x^n-1}{x^{4n}-1}\right)^3$$

Since $x^{37}=1,$

$$\sum_{n=1}^{36}n\left(\frac{x^n-1}{x^{4n}-1}\right)^3 $$
$$=\sum_{n=1}^{36}n\left(\frac{(x^{37})^{3n}x^n-1}{x^{4n}-1}\right)^3 $$
$$=\sum_{n=1}^{36}n\left(\frac{x^{112n}-1}{x^{4n}-1}\right)^3 $$
$$=\sum_{n=1}^{36}n(x^{108n}+x^{104n}+...+x^{4n}+1)^3 $$

But I have no idea how to continue.

Comment: Why do you believe it has a particularly simple form?

Comment: For $n=1,\dots,36$, $x^n$ is also a root of $z^{37}=1$.

Comment: What do you mean by 'normal form'?

Comment: Note that the cubed term in your last sum can be rewritten as
$$x^{108n}+\ldots+x^{4n}+1=-x^{5n}\frac{\Phi_2(x^n)\Phi_4(x^n)\Phi_{16}(x^n)}{\ \Phi_5(x^n)},$$
where $\Phi_k$ is the $k$-th cyclotomic polynomial, though comments are too short to contain its proof.

Comment: Mathematica says the real part is the rational number $26973/2 = 2^{-1}3^637$.

Comment: Calculations suggest that the real part is the same as Julian Rosen mentioned, but the imaginary part depends on which primitive $37^{th}$ root of unity is taken.